# How to translate PHP md5($src, TRUE) to Go

Tags: go, md5

PHP Source:

```php
echo base64_encode(md5("a", TRUE));
```

PHP Output: `DMF1ucDxtqgxw5niaXcmYQ==`

How do I use Go to do this?

Comment: This is not a code translation service. What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Use encoding/base64 and crypto/md5.

Answer (score 2):

This function will do the same as your PHP code above:

```golang
func base64MD5(text string) string {
    sum := md5.Sum([]byte(text))
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sum[:])
}
```

Example to execute on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NF_Vo9-LU7X)

Comment: why using sum[:]  instead of []byte(sum)

Comment: Because you can't convert an array to a slice with `[]byte(sum)`. See example: https://play.golang.org/p/DFzMWSQwil8. `sum[:]` creates a slice on top of the array containing all its elements.